# Server Disconnected due to error: Timeout

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer

I am having issue when using matchmaker whereby my client kicked off the server approximately 50sec and every time got an error:

`Server client disconnect error:1 UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkIdentity:UNetStaticUpdate() OnDisconnectError error:6 UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkIdentity:UNetStaticUpdate()`

When I googled someone said upgrade to 5.4.2p3 version doing so, I got the below error:

`Server Disconnected due to error: Timeout UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkIdentity:UNetStaticUpdate()`

I have seen so many links regarding this error but no one put correct solution to overcome this issue  Could anyone help me to figure out this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that there is something else hosting on that same port which is overriding your server. Try changing your server port.

Comment: Also to check that a port is clear, use Wireshark. Once you've downloaded it go to the wifi part, double click it and then set a filter at to top to udp.port==What ever your port is. If you see lots of packets appearing with that port than change it.